# How to define a field in Scala?

Tags: scala, field

Is there a way to force a class member to be a public field in Scala?

`class X {
  val number = 0
}`

I want `number` to be a public field; I don't want the default behaviour of a private field with getter / setter.

The only discussion that I can find is [this](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/2030), but there is no conclusive answer.

Thanks!

**Edit:** My particular use-case is to access the field via a scripting engine (Rhino/Nashorn). Though I would prefer to have a solution that is more general.

Comment: If you define a class like this `class Foo(val test:String)` and then create an instance of it like this `val f = new Foo("bar")` and then print it's declared fields via reflection like so `f.getClass().getDeclaredFields().toList foreach (f => println(f.getName()))` it seems to work fine to me.  What's the issue?

Comment: Also, in playing around with this a little with Java's Javascript Engine capabilities, I can pass in a scala object as defined above via `engine.put("myF", f)` and then println it via `engine.eval("println(myF.test())")`.  The only real nuance is that I have to include the `()` to invoke the function to get the value.  I don't think you're going to be able to get around that, so what's the big deal?

Comment: Well the hard part is that the javascript is third-party, not mine. I am exploring writing a macro for this. Or else I will rewrite my class in Java.

Comment: Since Java's Javascript binding is based on Rhino and the Rhino interpreter maps.. = XXX to getXXX and XXX = foo to setXXX(foo), if you mark the val with @BeanProperty, it should "just work"?

Comment: Looks like Nashorn (Javascript in Java8) does the same thing: http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/04/05/java8-nashorn-tutorial/ (search for "working with getters and setters")

Comment: @Paul thanks! Hadn't imagined that a `@BeanProperty` getter would get remapped by Rhino/Nashorn. Works swell!

Comment: I'll add my comment as an answer, then. Me? Reputation-whoring? Never :)

Answer (score 2):

Since Java's Javascript binding is based on Rhino and the Rhino interpreter maps.. = XXX to getXXX and XXX = foo to setXXX(foo), if you mark the val with @BeanProperty, it should "just work".

Looks like Nashorn (Javascript in Java8) does the same thing: winterbe.com/posts/2014/04/05/java8-nashorn-tutorial (search for "working with getters and setters"), so you should be future-proof, too.

Comment: This works fine for my particular use-case of accessing the field via Javascript engine. However, I will try to see if a macro will solve this for the general case.

Answer (score 1):

Modulo name mangling:

```
scala> object X { private[this] val x = 7 ; @inline def getX = x }
defined object X

scala> :javap -prv X
Binary file X contains $line5.$read$$iw$$iw$X$
[snip]
{
  public static final $line5.$read$$iw$$iw$X$ MODULE$;
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC, ACC_FINAL

  public final int $line5$$read$$iw$$iw$X$$x;
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_FINAL
```

Inlining the accessor loosens access to the field, which is name-mangled to avoid clashes. The odd name here is due to REPL templating.

Without REPL:

```
scala> classOf[x.X$].getDeclaredFields map (f => s"'${f.getName}'")
res1: Array[String] = Array('MODULE$', 'x$X$$x')
```

The normal private field is name-mangled in Scala reflection by appending a space; at least this mangling is visible to the naked eye.

Comment: Oh, that comes very close. Except for the additional space in the name, which kills my use-case. Do you think writing a macro for this is possible?

Answer (score -1):

You usually can see those vals by default - as they are public by default. You do not need setter and getter.

```
class TestIt {
    val normalClassVariable = 10
}

class CanYouSeeIt{
  var test:TestIt = new TestIt
  test.normalClassVariable
}
```

This works perfectly fine.

Edit: If you need more insight, try this link: http://daily-scala.blogspot.ch/2009/11/access-modifiers-public-private.html

Comment: Your example doesn't create a public field. It creates a private field with public getter method, which I don't want.

Comment: But it is public by default - why do you think it is private, as you can access it from other classes without the need of a getter or setter.

Comment: There is a getter/setter behind the syntax sugar. See this: http://www.vlad-yatsenko.eu/2012/08/scala-vs-java-properties/